# TextBlock sends my last word on a new line

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a textblock that's generated dinamicaly, containing two Runs, I use `TextWrapping.Wrap` and I set the width to maximum, the problem is that my last word get's on a new line even if there's enough space.

```
 StackPanel entry_holder = new StackPanel();
            TextBlock entry_title = new TextBlock();
            Run titleFragment = new Run();
            titleFragment.Text = newsPice.posterName;
            titleFragment.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 19,78,122));
            Run titleFragment2 = new Run();
            titleFragment2.Text = " " + newsPice.title;
            entry_title.Width = 400;
            entry_title.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            entry_title.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
            entry_title.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
            titleFragment.FlowDirection = System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            titleFragment2.FlowDirection = System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            entry_title.Inlines.Add(titleFragment);
            entry_title.Inlines.Add(titleFragment2);
```

"alin mihai" is the first run and "is eating vanilla shake dsfdsfsdsf" is the second run.
[image: Example in the image]

Comment: post relevant portion of your XAML

Comment: what are you using panorama or pivot as container ???

Comment: i updated the question with the code that generates the output